# blank page after password request submit

Tags: email, password, forgot-password

I have this issue after upgrading from EE 2.5.5 to 2.7.2. The new EE method to reset the password gives the right page, but after having submitted the reset form all I get just a blank homepage. Those are POST info:

```
ACT {AID:Member:send_reset_token}
FROM    
email   myemail@email.com
site_id 3
```

any idea on how I can debug this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the native forgot password method or one in a third party membership module like Zoo Visitor, User or Profile:Edit?

Comment: standart-native EE method

Comment: Can you please edit your question including relevant code from your templates?

Comment: I would really like to, but the reset page is an EE standard template, and the blank page is just a blank page :/ no errors whatsoever

Comment: Can you change the debug setting in your index.php to 1 and see if there are any errors when you submit the form?

Comment: already done, the blank pages gives no clue, I'm going to check logs tonight.